# How to set inbox sync time range in Mail?

Tags: mail.app

When I setup an email account in Mail seems like Mail insists on downloading the tens of thousands of emails I have between now and years way back. How do I tell it to sync only in a specific time range like 3 months for example?

Thanks

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112454/how-do-i-limit-caching-in-mail-for-mavericks

Comment: However, gmail has a workaround to prevent too many downloads over IMAP. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95071/avoid-download-100-000-mails-to-use-apple-mail

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately my company uses Yahoo business.