# How to download only recent mails in Apple Mail.app on El Capitan?

Tags: mail.app, macos

I have an account at Hotmail/Outlook.com and I have lots of mails there since 2006 (dozens of GB). I am using IMAP and I don't want Mail.app to download them all, also because I have really slow connection (and I dont care about my emails from 2006.)

Is there a way to make Mail.app download only mails more recent than, for example, 10 or 30 days ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible in Mail.app.

As a workaround, [your e-mail provider may allow you to limit the amount of e-mails available over IMAP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/90579/5472).